# Use Query As DAO.Recordset

Tags: ms-access, vba, dao, ms-access-2013

I am attempting to iterate a query as a `DAO.Recordset`, my issue is that my recordset never prints anything.  If I look at my table, and my query both of them have the data that I am after, but the VBA is not producing the data that I expect.  Below is synatx - why will this not write my data?

```
Option Compare Database
Sub Test()

Dim query1 As String, rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim qryDef As QueryDef, strSQL As String

query1 = "qryPullData"

strSQL = "SELECT fl1 As [Field With Spaces One],fl2 As [Field With Spaces Two], " & _
     "fl3 As [Field WIth Spaces Three], fl4 As [Field With Spaces Four] " & _
     "FROM smallsubset ORDER BY fl1 ASC;"

Set qryDef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(query1, strSQL)


Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query1)

If Not rs1.EOF Then
    While Not rs1.EOF
            Debug.Print rs1("Field With Spaces One")
            Debug.Print rs1("Field With Spaces Two")
            Debug.Print rs1("Field With Spaces Three")
            Debug.Print rs1("Field With Spaces Four")
            Debug.Print rs1("[Field With Spaces One]")
            Debug.Print rs1("[Field With Spaces Two]")
            Debug.Print rs1("[Field With Spaces Three]")
            Debug.Print rs1("[Field With Spaces Four]")
    Wend
    rs1.Close
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `rsExportExcel` is not declared - do you have a typo there?  Also you are missing a `MoveNext` unless you *want* an infinite loop

Comment: @TimWilliams - yes, my mistake that should be rs1

Comment: do es your code enter the `While` loop ?

Comment: @TimWilliams - yes, if I step through my code, each line is hit, but the Debug.Print never prints anything.  If I manually run the query qryPullData it has all the information I am after.

Comment: Try `Debug.Print ">" & rs1("Field With Spaces One").Value & "<" ` what prints?

Comment: @TimWilliams - adding .Value still prints nothing.  I tried both instances of with the bracket and w/o

Comment: "Nothing" means not even the "><" ?

Comment: @TimWilliams - no I apologize, it prints the ><, just not the value from the query.

Comment: If you omit the field aliases does it work?  And you can drop the trailing semicolon from the SQL

Comment: @TimWilliams - no if I omit the aliases, i.e. use actual field names from the table it still only prints ><

Comment: Is this your full, *exact* code? Have you `Option Explicit` at the top of the module? -- Where is `rs1.MoveNext` ?

Comment: If you manually open the query what data is in the very first record? And yes, you definitely need `rs1.MoveNext` just before the `Wend`. Also, you don't really need the `If` ... `End If` block; if `rs1.EOF` is True then it won't enter the `While` loop. To tidy up you should replace `rs1.Close` with `Set rs1 = Nothing` and `Set qryDef = Nothing`. In fact, thinking about it, once you've created the query "qryPullData" you will get an error if you run this code again without manually deleting this query first.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code using several of the suggestions from the above comments:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim query1 As String, rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qryDef As QueryDef, strSQL As String

    If CheckQuery("qryPullData") = "Yes" Then
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "qryPullData"
    End If

    query1 = "qryPullData"

    strSQL = "SELECT fl1 As [Field With Spaces One],fl2 As [Field With Spaces Two], " & _
    "fl3 As [Field WIth Spaces Three], fl4 As [Field With Spaces Four] " & _
    "FROM smallsubset ORDER BY fl1 ASC;"

    Set qryDef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(query1, strSQL)

    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query1)
    rs1.MoveFirst

    While Not rs1.EOF
        Debug.Print rs1("Field With Spaces One")
        Debug.Print rs1("Field With Spaces Two")
        Debug.Print rs1("Field With Spaces Three")
        Debug.Print rs1("Field With Spaces Four")
        rs1.MoveNext
    Wend
    rs1.Close

End Sub
```

Here is the CheckQuery sub stolen from here: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=206298

```
Function CheckQuery(queryName As String)
    Dim qryLoop As QueryDef
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim exists As String

    exists = "No"
    For Each qryLoop In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        If qryLoop.Name = queryName Then
            exists = "Yes"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    CheckQuery = exists
End Function
```

Make sure that you are looking in the immediate window for the Debug.Print results.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly tidier version of code from @tlemaster. This will format your output a little better rather than just running all the fields and records together one after the other, removes unnecessary variables from the `CheckQuery` function and properly releases all the object variables.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qryDef As QueryDef
    Dim query1 As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lngRecordNum As Long    '(how many records are you expecting?)

    query1 = "qryPullData"

    If QueryExists(query1) Then
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, query1
    End If

    strSQL = "SELECT fl1 As [Field With Spaces One], fl2 As [Field With Spaces Two], " & _
    "fl3 As [Field WIth Spaces Three], fl4 As [Field With Spaces Four] " & _
    "FROM smallsubset ORDER BY fl1 ASC;"

    Set qryDef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(query1, strSQL)

    Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(query1)

    lngRecordNum = 1
    Do While Not rs1.EOF
        Debug.Print "Record " & lngRecordNum & ":"
        Debug.Print "    " & rs1("Field With Spaces One")
        Debug.Print "    " & rs1("Field With Spaces Two")
        Debug.Print "    " & rs1("Field With Spaces Three")
        Debug.Print "    " & rs1("Field With Spaces Four")
        rs1.MoveNext
    Loop

    Set rs1 = Nothing
    Set qryDef = Nothing

End Sub


Public Function QueryExists(queryName As String) As Boolean

    Dim qryLoop As QueryDef

    For Each qryLoop In CurrentDb.QueryDefs
        If qryLoop.Name = queryName Then
            QueryExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set qryLoop = Nothing

End Function
```